# "#Include" appears in "struct" in C language

Tags: c

I saw such a usage when reading the code

```
struct conf_param conf_params[] = 
{
#include "s2conf.h"
    { NULL }
};
```

I don’t understand what this "#include" does?
Will it put everything in the "s2conf.h" file into "conf_params"?

=========================s2conf.h======================

```
#ifndef _s2conf_h_
#define _s2conf_h_

#include "rt.h"

#define DFLT_LOGFILE_SIZE        "\"10MB\""
#define DFLT_LOGFILE_ROTATE             "3"
#define DFLT_CUPS_BUFSZ           "\"8KB\""
/* TC */
#define DFLT_MAX_RXDATA           (10*1024)
#define DFLT_MAX_TXDATA           (16*1024)
#define DFLT_MAX_WSSDATA               2048
#define DFLT_TC_RECV_BUFSZ        (40*1024)
#define DFLT_TC_SEND_BUFSZ        (80*1024)
#define DFLT_RADIO_INIT_WAIT    "\"200ms\""
#define DFLT_MAX_TXUNITS                  4
#define DFLT_MAX_130X                     8
#define DFLT_MAX_TXJOBS                 128
#define DFLT_MAX_RXJOBS                  64
#define DFLT_RADIODEV  "\"/dev/spidev?.0\""
#define DFLT_TX_MIN_GAP          "\"10ms\""   // worst case for ODU as of 07.2018 (horrible SPI performance)
#define DFLT_TX_AIM_GAP          "\"20ms\""   //  -ditto-
#define DFLT_TX_MAX_AHEAD        "\"600s\""
#define DFLT_TXCHECK_FUDGE        "\"5ms\""
/* TCP keepalive */
#define DFLT_TCP_KEEPALIVE              "1"   // Connections use keep alive
#define DFLT_TCP_KEEPIDLE              "60"   // Connection idle time (in seconds) before sending keepalive probes
#define DFLT_TCP_KEEPINTVL             "15"   // The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes
#define DFLT_TCP_KEEPCNT                "4"   // The maximum number of keepalive probes sent before dropping the connection

#define DFLT_MAX_RMTSH                    2   // The maximum number of keepalive probes sent before dropping the connection
#define DFLT_BEACON_INTVL        "\"128s\""   // Time between beacons in microseconds




#if defined(CFG_platform_cisco) || defined(CFG_platform_rpi64)
#undef DFLT_TX_MIN_GAP
#undef DFLT_TX_AIM_GAP
#define DFLT_TX_MIN_GAP          "\"10ms\""
#define DFLT_TX_AIM_GAP          "\"60ms\""
#endif // defined(CFG_platform_cisco)




// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Flash specs
//
//      _ FLASH_ADDR         _ FLASH_BEG_A   _ FLASH_BEG_B
// |___/____________________/.............../..............._____|_BYTES_
// |   \                  _/\________             _________/  /  | PAGES
//      \   FS_PAGE_START             FS_PAGE_CNT            /
//       \________________                __________________/
//                         FLASH_PAGE_CNT
//
//  - FLASH_ADDR, FLASH_PAGE_CNT define addressible flash.
//  - FS_PAGE_START, FS_PAGE_CNT define location of FS inside addressible flash
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define FLASH_PAGE_SIZE  (4*1024)
#define FLASH_PAGE_CNT   (1024)
#define FLASH_SIZE       (FLASH_PAGE_CNT*FLASH_PAGE_SIZE)
#define FLASH_ADDR       (0*FLASH_PAGE_SIZE)
#define FLASH_ERASED     ((u4_t)0xFFFFFFFF)
#define FS_PAGE_START    (512)
#define FS_PAGE_CNT      (500)
#define FS_MAX_FD        8
#define FS_MAX_FNSIZE    256

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Non Lora runtime parameters
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

enum {  MAX_DEVICE_LEN = 64 };      // max size of SPI/FTDI etc radio device
enum {  MAX_HOSTNAME_LEN = 128 };   // max size of FQDN in a URI or elsewhere
enum {  MAX_PORT_LEN = 16 };        // max size of port section in a URI
enum {  MAX_URI_LEN = 128 };        // max size of a URI
enum {  MAX_FILEPATH_LEN = 256 };   

enum {  TC_RECV_BUFFER_SIZE =   DFLT_TC_RECV_BUFSZ }; // websocket connections to TC (infos/muxs)
enum {  TC_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE =   DFLT_TC_SEND_BUFSZ };

enum {  MAX_HWSPEC_SIZE = 32 };
enum {  MAX_CMDARGS = 64 };
enum {  MUXS_PROTOCOL_VERSION = 2 };
enum {  MAX_RMTSH = DFLT_MAX_RMTSH };

enum {  LOGLINE_LEN = 512 };

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Lora processing
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

enum {  RTT_SAMPLES     = 100 };
enum {  MAX_WSSFRAMES   =  32 };
enum {  MIN_UPJSON_SIZE = 384 };
enum {  MAX_TXUNITS     = DFLT_MAX_TXUNITS };
enum {  MAX_130X        = DFLT_MAX_130X };
enum {  MAX_TXJOBS      = DFLT_MAX_TXJOBS  };
enum {  MAX_TXFRAME_LEN =  255 };
enum {  MAX_RXFRAME_LEN =  255 };
enum {  MAX_RXJOBS      = DFLT_MAX_RXJOBS };
enum {  TXPOW_SCALE     =   10 };   // keep TX power internally as s2_t scaled by this
enum {  MAX_RXDATA      = DFLT_MAX_RXDATA };
enum {  MAX_TXDATA      = DFLT_MAX_TXDATA };
enum {  MAX_WSSDATA     = DFLT_MAX_WSSDATA };

/*
 *
 */
struct conf_param
{
    str_t name;
    str_t type;
    str_t info;
    str_t src;
    str_t value;
    void* pvalue;
    int (*parseFn)(struct conf_param* param);
};

extern struct conf_param conf_params[];

void  s2conf_ini ();
int   s2conf_set (str_t src, str_t name, str_t value);
void* s2conf_get (str_t name);   // it name a config param?
void  s2conf_printAll ();

#endif // _s2conf_h_

#ifndef _s2conf_x_
#define _s2conf_x_

#ifndef CONF_PARAM
#define CONF_PARAM(name,type,fn,value,info) extern type##_t name;
#endif

CONF_PARAM(RADIODEV            , str   , str     ,        DFLT_RADIODEV, "default radio device")
CONF_PARAM(LOGFILE_SIZE        , u4    , size_mb ,    DFLT_LOGFILE_SIZE, "default size of a logfile")
CONF_PARAM(LOGFILE_ROTATE      , u4    , u4      ,  DFLT_LOGFILE_ROTATE, "besides current log file keep *.1..N (none if 0)")
CONF_PARAM(TCP_KEEPALIVE_EN    , u4    , u4      ,   DFLT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, "TCP keepalive enabled")
CONF_PARAM(TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE  , u4    , u4      ,    DFLT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, "TCP keepalive TCP_KEEPIDLE [s]")
CONF_PARAM(TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTVL , u4    , u4      ,   DFLT_TCP_KEEPINTVL, "TCP keepalive TCP_KEEPINTVL [s]")
CONF_PARAM(TCP_KEEPALIVE_CNT   , u4    , u4      ,     DFLT_TCP_KEEPCNT, "TCP keepalive TCP_KEEPCNT")
CONF_PARAM(MAX_JOINEUI_RANGES  , u4    , u4      ,                 "10", "max ranges to suppress unwanted join requests")
CONF_PARAM(CUPS_CONN_TIMEOUT   , ustime, tspan_s ,            "\"60s\"", "connection timeout")
CONF_PARAM(CUPS_OKSYNC_INTV    , ustime, tspan_h ,            "\"24h\"", "regular check-in with CUPS for updates")
CONF_PARAM(CUPS_RESYNC_INTV    , ustime, tspan_m ,             "\"1m\"", "check-in with CUPS for updates after a failure")
CONF_PARAM(CUPS_BUFSZ          , u4    , size_kb ,      DFLT_CUPS_BUFSZ, "read from CUPS in chunks of this size")
CONF_PARAM(GPS_REPORT_DELAY    , ustime, tspan_s ,           "\"120s\"", "delay GPS reports and consolidate")
CONF_PARAM(GPS_REOPEN_TTY_INTV , ustime, tspan_ms,             "\"1s\"", "recheck TTY open if it failed")
CONF_PARAM(GPS_REOPEN_FIFO_INTV, ustime, tspan_ms,             "\"1s\"", "recheck if FIFO writer fake GPS")
CONF_PARAM(CMD_REOPEN_FIFO_INTV, ustime, tspan_ms,             "\"1s\"", "recheck if FIFO writer")
CONF_PARAM(RX_POLL_INTV        , ustime, tspan_ms,           "\"20ms\"", "interval to poll SX1301 RX FIFO")
CONF_PARAM(TC_TIMEOUT          , ustime, tspan_s ,            "\"60s\"", "reconnected to muxs")
CONF_PARAM(CLASS_C_BACKOFF_BY  , ustime, tspan_s ,          "\"100ms\"", "retry interval for class C TX attempts")
CONF_PARAM(CLASS_C_BACKOFF_MAX , u4    , u4      ,                 "10", "max number of class C TX attempts")
CONF_PARAM(RADIO_INIT_WAIT     , ustime, tspan_s , DFLT_RADIO_INIT_WAIT, "max wait for radio init command to finish")
CONF_PARAM(PPS_VALID_INTV      , ustime, tspan_ms,            "\"10m\"", "max age of last PPS sync for GPS time conversions")
CONF_PARAM(TIMESYNC_RADIO_INTV , ustime, tspan_ms,         "\"2100ms\"", "interval to resync MCU/SX1301")
CONF_PARAM(TIMESYNC_LNS_RETRY  , ustime, tspan_s ,           "\"71ms\"", "resend timesync message to server")
CONF_PARAM(TIMESYNC_LNS_PAUSE  , ustime, tspan_s ,             "\"5s\"", "pause after unsuccessful volley of timesync messages")
CONF_PARAM(TIMESYNC_LNS_BURST  , u4    , u4      ,                 "10", "volley of timesync messages before pausing")
CONF_PARAM(TIMESYNC_REPORTS    , ustime, tspan_s ,             "\"5m\"", "report interval for current timesync status")
CONF_PARAM(TX_MIN_GAP          , ustime, tspan_s ,      DFLT_TX_MIN_GAP, "min distance between two frames being TXed")
CONF_PARAM(TX_AIM_GAP          , ustime, tspan_s ,      DFLT_TX_AIM_GAP, "aim for this TX lead time, if delayed should not fall under min")
CONF_PARAM(TX_MAX_AHEAD        , ustime, tspan_s ,    DFLT_TX_MAX_AHEAD, "maximum time message can be scheduled into the future")
CONF_PARAM(TXCHECK_FUDGE       , ustime, tspan_s ,   DFLT_TXCHECK_FUDGE, "check radio state this time into ongoing TX")
CONF_PARAM(BEACON_INTVL        , ustime, tspan_s ,    DFLT_BEACON_INTVL, "beaconing interval")
CONF_PARAM(TLS_SNI             ,     u4,    bool ,               "true", "Set and verify server name of TLS connections")

#endif // _s2conf_x_
```

This is the content in "s2conf.h". There are many things in this, will they be included in "conf_params"?

Comment: "_I don’t understand what this "#include" does?_" Do you know what `#include` does in general? Here, it does the same thing.

Comment: `#include` is, very simplified, like copy-paste but for files. It basically copies the contents of the file specified (`s2conf.h` in your case), and pastes it in place of the `#include` directive.

Comment: Notably, this is also poor style and should be avoided. It would have been far more readable to include the struct type in the same file as the initializer list.

Comment: The `s2conf.h` file you show will not work when included in the place it's shown, at least not with the context you show. Please include more context, like possible macro definitions before and after `conf_params`.

Answer (score 4):

When the preprocessor encounters

```
#include "foo"
```

it replaces that line with the contents of `foo`. Your example is uncommon, but no exception. You need to look at `s2conf.h` to know what the code is after preprocessing. Style is debatable, but at least the `.h` extension is misleading and should be changed.

Comment: A common scheme here is to emphasize the special kind of include category via an .inl suffix for the header's name or something similar.

Comment: @ningxu note that your answer is not an answer. You can edit your question if you want to add more details. Just don't be surprised if your answer might collect a downvote or two

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I am a novice

Comment: @ningxu ok, now consider that I answered the question you wrote initially. Your edit turned it basically into a different question. I should have not answered before the question was clarified, but I did and now my answer doesnt really answer your question. Best is not to modify the question to ask for something else once you got answers. Nevermind, maybe someone else will write a new one

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 OK，Thanks~